# conditional ON (join condition) in sql using different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

I need to use conditional ON clause, with the need to place a different column condition in case of if true and in case of if false
Here is the example

```
select a.* b.*
 from tblA a inner join tblB b
 on a.somefield = b.someOtherField
 AND 
 /*THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM STARTS, I am using pseudo code, and need help with the actual code
 (
   if substring(a.field3, 1,3) <>'' - I want to use substring(a.field3, 1,3)=b.field2
   else, I want to use say b.field5='Y'
 )
 */
```

So, effectively in case of IF evaluating to true, I want a select of this kind:

```
select a.* b.*
 from tblA a inner join tblB b
 on a.somefield = b.someOtherField
 **AND substring(a.field3, 1,3)=b.field2**
```

And if condition is false, I want the effective join clause to be

```
    select a.* b.*
 from tblA a inner join tblB b
 on a.somefield = b.someOtherField
 **AND b.field5='Y'**
```

Using SQL Server

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use boolean logic:

```
select a.* b.*
from tblA a inner join
     tblB b
     on a.somefield = b.someOtherField AND
        ((substring(a.field3, 1, 3) <> '' and substring(a.field3, 1,3) = b.field2) or
         ( (substring(a.field3, 1, 3) = '' or a.field3 is null) and b.field5 = 'Y'
        );
```

For clarity, I used `substring()` in the second clause. It can equally be written as:

```
         (a.field3 = '' and b.field5 = 'Y')
```

because if the substring is `''`, then so is the original string.